# do we need to declare something in manifest to support mutiple screens.

Tags: android

do i have to declare anything in manifest for all ldpi and hdlp i
because my ldpi is not showing the full screen it is cutting off. can any one help on this

Thanks 
MAx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is nothing to declare in the manifest for density. There are `<supports-screens>` and `<compatible-screens>` that you can declare for screen sizes.

Comment: <compatible-screens> does have density attributes: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using fixed heights/widths declared in px (pixels) your app will only support different screen sizes and densities.

Be sure to always use  dp/dip (density independant pixels) when declaring static height or width but try to use `match_parent` (or `fill_parent`) or `wrap_content` as much as possible.